# What is the normal Perception penalty while sleeping?

Tags: skills, anima-beyond-fantasy

**What is the normal penalty a character receives to their perception scores while sleeping?**

Characters are implied to have limited ability to use their perception skills while sleeping.  The advantage *Light Sleeper* explains that a character who possesses it receives "only" a -20 to Notice while sleeping, implying that the normal penalty is greater.  Meanwhile, the disadvantage *Deep Sleeper* gives a character a staggering -200.  Clearly, the default state is somewhere between these two values.

This default value does not seem to appear in the advantages/disadvantages section around *Light Sleeper* or *Deep Sleeper*, nor in the Secondary Abilities section around the Perception skills (despite having a chart of modifiers where it would fit nicely), nor in the States and Accidents section detailing status effects.  **Where can I find this value?**

Comment: Been searching the book on and over and couldn't find the reference for this (I know it´s -80 anyway). The only reference are the Spanish official forums http://www.edgeent.com/tema/28379-advertir_dormido Not adding it as an answer since it is a link (to a Spanish place) and it is not RAW.

Comment: @Random Wouldn't the official forums be considered a credible source?  If it doesn't exist in any book due to a mistake, forum sites would be our only alternative and next-best option.

Comment: I would have preferred to find it in a bard circle (the meetings the creator of the game had with the fans) or in the proper book, but these forums are a credible source, since it is a really good community and very knowledgeable on Anima rules.

Comment: @Random Then feel free to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best reference I can find is in [the Spanish official forum](http://www.edgeent.com/tema/28379-advertir_dormido). Not RAW, but possibly the second best thing. 
The answer seems to be -80.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the more-authoritative places where it *isn't*? Like "Nothing in the book, the bard circle didn't address it, but the forum...." Sort of an argument that this is the most-authoritative extant source?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not posses the transcritps of the bard circles, so I cannot help there.

Comment: @Random I think nitsua60 is just saying that you should add something like "It doesn't exist in the core book" to your answer to clarify why you're giving a "not RAW" answer.  I think it's probably fine, though, as I covered those cases in the question.